# Best way to get links from strings that contain them

Tags: c#, regex, string, hyperlink, substring

I have a list of links, but I need to FILTER-OUT and EXTRACT correct links from the String.

Extract should start with mywebsite.com and which end with 9-digitnumber.html
Links are strings, extracted to string

Example

```
http://blah.com?f=www.mywebsite.com/sdfsf/sdfsdf/sdfsdfsdf/123456789.html&sdfsdf/sf/sdfsd8sdfsdfsdf
```

and so on...

From this, regex must extract

```
mywebsite.com/sdfsf/sdfsdf/sdfsdfsdf/123456789.html
```

This should match the number in the end
'@"[0-9]{9}".  but I am very new to regex and trying to learn how to use it properly

Comment: Must it be a regex? What is the source of data? Do you have more examples?

Comment: Also - [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: parameters  should not contain `/`. It must be escaped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML with regexs is usually a bad idea. For you particular example, you can use:

```
(mywebsite.com/(.+?)\d{9})
```

but as Andrew said, using a regex for doing what you want is not really necessary.

Comment: lnk=Regex.Match(val, @"mywebsite.com/(.+?)\d{9}").ToString();  worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
/mywebsite\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/]*[0-9]{9}\.html/
```

Comment: I tried `String lnk=Regex.Match(val, @"/mysite\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/]*[0-9]{9}\.html/").ToString();` and it does not work

Comment: @Andrew I know nothing about C#, but try `String lnk=Regex.Match(val, @"mywebsite\.com\/[a-zA-Z0-9\/]*[0-9]{9}\.html").ToString();`

Comment: @Andrew Also you typed `mysite` instead of `mywebsite`, which might be the problem.

Comment: @Andrew what was the value of `val`?